# using functions in dll, in java

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface

I have some dll files(not custom and not written by me) and I need to use the functions, that are c/c++ written, in these files in my java project. I googled and read many examples about JNI but they were all about writing your own program and dll and then reaching them. Also I don't think dllexport exists in these dlls, so dllimport/dllexport method is not available I guess.
How can I reach these functions?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have a look at JNA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure, you looked at the JNI Tutorial at oracle already. I had a quick look at the part, where a [native function is implemented and a dll is compiled](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html#impl) and I don't think, that special conditions have to be met.

I'd give it a try with a single, easy function from that dll:

1. Write a [simple clas](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html#examp)s with just main method that uses one of the native methods (with easy parameters to have an easy start)
2. [Generate](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html#gen) the header file and
3. [run](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html#run) the test application

If the dll is not 'jni compliant' (whatever that means), you'll know by then and then you probably know that you have to recompile the native code.

Comment: And if the source code for the DLL is not available, write some 'native' source code that calls the DLL.